# Display and modify Dictionary<string, List<string>> with a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display a `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>>` into a wpf datagrid.
The key is the column and values are rows for the column something like this:

Key1                     Key2

Value1Key1            Value1Key2

Value2Key1            Value2Key2

Value3Key1            Value3Key2

I want to be able to display, modify either columns and rows values to get my `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>>`  back in an easy way.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Any reason you don't use a dataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>>` and bind the string to a column header, and the `ObservableCollection<string>>` to the column.

Comment: Sorry I already use this Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>> but there was a bad text formatting in my question.

Comment: I do this for header:'foreach (string s in entries.Keys)
                dataGrid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = s });dataGrid1.ItemsSource=entries.Values;'

Comment: The columns are displayed correctly, but I can get my list displayed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have internet service :(. I'm glad you could solved it :)

Comment: Hi Ramin - any chance you could post the code - if you can find it? it will help future users. chrs